# LCD full graphic smart controller, no character display and screen blinking

Tags: marlin, full-graphic-smart-controller

After uncommenting the `REPRAP_DISCOUNT_FULL_GRAPHIC_SMART_CONTROLLER`, the display is blinking and no characters are shown on the screen, I have already switched the cables between `EXP1` and `EXP2`, but it did not succeed.

Comment: This question could use some more information and pictures. It is a fact that some of the cheap displays have the EXP ports upside down, I have had that myself so I cut out some slots for the notches on the cable connector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this problem can be solved by turning the slots on the display, as in the image below. Some Chinese displays are inverted from factory.

[image]

Comment: Yes, my experience was the same, I didn't know you could turn the plastic all the way around, good to know for next time! I just cut some extra slots...

Comment: I've just switched the slots and it worked like a charm, it made my day!